# Strange situation regarding website appearance on Google

Tags: php, html, forms, url, field

So I have a member based website that I submitted to Google. I suppose I accidentally submitted the url with had member's info on it.

For example.

Normal website url.

http://www.mywebsite.com

Submitted website url.

http://www.mywebsite.com

I have a signup form on the index page. And I believe I accidentally used the url when those fields were filled in the input.

So now, the www. extension is associated with those input fields. Every time I use www.mywebsite.com, those input fields with info show up; where if I just use mywebsite.com, the fields will return empty.

I re-submited my website to Google with input fields empty.  Hopefully that does the trick, but I am not 100% on that.

What you think?

Comment: You need to wait till Google **recrawls** your website. :) Nothing else.

Comment: Understood. Will do that :)

Comment: Could it be your fields are being filled by the browser? Try accessing through a different browser.

Comment: Ahh yes. First of all, it was only Firefox that was inputing the fields. Chrome and Opera were fine.  Second, I had to add autocomplete="off" to the sign up form input fields. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is to wait till Google **recrawls** your website. Other than that you can add your website in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and try to play with it.

Comment: I just removed the old url and added the new one on webmaster tools. Hopefully that's it.   Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just resubmit your website to google using webmasters tool.. And wait till its indexed again